# Custom cypress command that returns when apex page ready

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, cypress, dom-events

I'm trying to make cypress work for Oracle apex. However, it seems that the page is not fully loaded when returning from my custom command.

I want to do `return w.apex;` only when the apex event "apexreadyend" has been triggered (this is the last event in a page load for oracle apex).

How can I do this?
Or maybe this can be called after each page load?

I have managed to make this custom command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("apex", () => {

    cy.window().then((w) => {
        return w.apex;
    });
});
```

Update:
I think the event 'apexreadyend' has already happened at this point, making this useless.
Instead I went for a check on the body:

```
cy.get('body').should('not.have.class','no-anim')
```

However, A custom theme might not use this class.
So it is not a very good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your event in a Promise. The Cypress docs have an example about [waiting for a Promise to complete](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises). For your event, it would look something like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("apex", () => {
  const EVENT_NAME = "apexreadyend"
  return cy.window() // get a handle for the window
  .then($win => {
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
      const onReady = () => {
        $win.removeEventListener(EVENT_NAME, onReady) // cleanup
        resolve() // resolve and allow Cypress to continue
      }
      $win.addEventListener(EVENT_NAME, onReady)
    })
  })
})
```

Then stuff like this would work:

```js
cy.apex() // wait for `apexreadyend` to fire
// do some assertions here that will only pass after apexreadyend
```

Comment: This seems good, however, im getting an error:

CypressError: cy.then() timed out after waiting '4000ms'.

Your callback function returned a promise which never resolved.

The callback function was:

function ($win) {
    return new Cypress.Promise(function (resolve) {
      var onReady = function onReady() {
        $win.removeEventListener(EVENT_NAME, onReady); // cleanup

        resolve(); // resolve and allow Cypress to continue
      };

      $win.addEventListener(EVENT_NAME, onReady);
    });
  }

Comment: You can increase the timeout on the `then` if it's too short. Something like this: `.then({ timeout: 30000 }, $win => {` would set the timeout to 30 seconds

Comment: You might also need a `cy.document().addEventListener()` instead depending on where your event fires, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582982/how-to-listen-global-events-with-cypress/55583108#55583108

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait until `window.apex` exists? Thanks to Cypress's retry logic, you actually don't need to listen to an event for this functionality. You can just use [`cy.its()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/its.html) to grab the value of the property once it is defined:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("apex", () => {
  return cy.window()
  .its('apex') // will automatically retry until `window.apex` exists
               // or until the default timeout occurs
})
```

Then you should be able to use it like this:

```js
it('something apex', function() {
  cy.apex().then(apex => {
    // do whatever you want with the apex object
  })
  // or, since it's wrapped, can also just do assertions like this:
  cy.apex().its('some-property').should('equal', 'abc123')
})
```