# How to listen global events with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

We have an application that polls the server periodically until a task is completed. We fire a global event so that Cypress can catch and find out if the task is finished but we had trouble using `document.addEventListener` on Cypress. Here's what we're doing:

```
document.addEventListener('queryEnd', () => {
    cy.get('.chart').should('be.visible')
    cy.get('.table').should('be.visible')
  })
```

However; when we use it in a spec, it doesn't work expected and we're not able to catch it. Also, Cypress doesn't wait for the test and runs `afterEach` without waiting for the callback to run.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working like you expect is because in Cypress, your tests run in a separate frame than your application under test (AUT). The event you're waiting for will never fire inside of Cypress's `document`.

To get the `document` of the AUT, use [`cy.document()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/document.html#Syntax) like this:

```js
cy.document()
.then($document => {
  // now $document is a reference to the AUT Document
  $document.addEventListener(...)
})
```

To make Cypress wait for your event before continuing, you can just wrap it in a `Cypress.Promise`. The Cypress docs have an example about [waiting for a Promise to complete](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Waiting-for-Promises). For your `queryEnd` event, it would look something like this:

```js
cy.document() // get a handle for the document
.then($document => {
  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => { // Cypress will wait for this Promise to resolve
    const onQueryEnd = () => {
      $document.removeEventListener('queryEnd', onQueryEnd) // cleanup
      resolve() // resolve and allow Cypress to continue
    }
    $document.addEventListener('queryEnd', onQueryEnd)
  })
})
.then(() => {
  cy.get('.chart').should('be.visible')
  cy.get('.table').should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: Should it work for event `shiny:value` described here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html ?

Comment: @AdamB yes it should

Comment: It seems complicated to avoid race conditions, because the event listener is added after `cy.visit`, there might be a risk that the event is already fired by that time. Using `cy.window()` feels more reliable because the `window` object is available much sooner than `window.document`.

Comment: @EricBurel Great point. It would be best to add this as a `cy.visit` `onBeforeLoad` callback, not as a `cy.document().then` or `cy.window().then`, for the reason you describe: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Provide-an-onBeforeLoad-callback-function

Comment: Even better than this, is adding a listener for an event, explicitly causing that event to occur (like with a cy.click()), and then asserting that it happened. No race conditions if you are able to order your app's actions like this. But it can be difficult for things that only occur on load.

Comment: You should post the  `onBeforeLoad` thing as an answer, I think that might be the best approach. Do you have access to `cy.` stuffs in this callback? If no, we can still use it to set a global variable when the event is fired for instance, and check this variable later on.
The problem with triggering the event manually is that it's not always possible (here, I want to tell when a WebGL render is done on the page, so it's fired immediately)

Comment: Gave a shot at `onBeforeLoad`: it works ok, however you must be careful because it won't wait contrary to usual `cy.*` commands. So if you do `cy.visit("/foobar", onBeforeLoad: (win) => { win.addEventListener("foobar", () => { cy.expect(true).toBe(true)}) } })`, the  `cy.expect` won't wait. So you still need an additional command to wait for the event before leaving.

Comment: Opened a feature request: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16793